# Read Downloaded Text File - Android - error - FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the data from this google translate API URL:

```
String sourceLang = "auto";
String targetLang = "en";
String sourceText = "olas";
String urlstring = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + sourceText;
```

the api url works good on python, but on android i get the filenotfoundexception error.

mabye its because the url download a .txt file instead of showing the data, as u can see:

https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=en&dt=t&q=olas

this is the code i used:

```
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLconnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add user agent to your httpURLconnection.

```
 HttpURLConnection httpURLconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 httpURLconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","MyAppName/1.0");
```

Comment: done! but it gives the same error when the value is more than 1 word..
i mean:
String sourceText = "olas";
works
but 
String sourceText = "olas olas";
dosent work